# how to reference a cell in another excel worksheet using ID from a formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Please help me to figure out how to reference a particular item in another tab (worksheet).
I saw the reference with VBA, but I'm trying to see if this can be done with formula first.
This will be a summary page, and I need to display values stored in the same location Q20 from all the sheets. I'm looking for something like:
='week03-Nov6'!Q25

so that I can copy it to the next cell to produce a series:
='week04-Nov13'!Q25
='week05-Nov20'!Q25

I would like to replay the 'weekXX-DateXX' with some SHEET(ID).
Is that possible without VBA?

Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Indirect`.  Put this in A1,

`=INDIRECT("'week0"&B1&"-Nov"&C1&"'!A1")`

Then, in B1 and C1, you can put `3` and `6` (respectively), and the formula will basically return Cell A1 from `Week03-Nov6` sheet.

You can tweak/adjust/add as necessary. Let me know if you aren't able to get this working!